# How update sqlite column in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I try to update column like this:

```
db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
       resultSaver) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); ",
        "UPDATE typingResult SET resultArray = (?) wordsTyped = (?) testTaken = (?) accuracy = (?) correctAmount = (?) resultSaver = (?) WHERE correctAmount > 0 ; ",

        ['something', 211, 2, 86.2, 121, 'something234'],

        (_, result) => {
            resolve(result);
        },
        (_, err) => {
            reject(err);
        }
      );
    })
```

I get this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: near "wordsTyped": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: UPDATE typingResult SET resultArray = (?) wordsTyped = (?) testTaken = (?) accuracy = (?) correctAmount = (?) resultSaver = (?)]

Where can I get more information about expo-sqlite ?